# Есть ли иной подход получения информации при помощи TCP в C#?

Tags: c#, tcp

Я использую следующий код для получения массива байт:

```
    void Reciever()
    {
        var client = new TcpClient();
        client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 1010);

        while (true)
        {
            if (client.Available > 0)
            {                    
                var bytes = new BinaryReader(client.GetStream()).ReadBytes(client.Available);
                Process(bytes);
            }
        }
    }
```

Есть ли иной способ проверки того, поступила ли новая информация на сокет? (Без постоянной проверки свойства TcpClient.Available)

Comment: И есть ли в .NET реализация сокета, при поступлении информации на который будет вызван ивент?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант можно использовать класс `Socket` вместо `TcpClient`.
После `connect` используйте `socket.Receive(data_buffer, _data_length, options)`.
Этот метод ожидает появления данных и считывает появившиеся данные в буфер, переданный первым аргументом.

Ваш код в таком случае преобразуется так:

```
void Reciever()
    {
        var client_socket = new Socket();
        socket.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 1010);
        byte[] recieved_data = new byte[256]; // Размер данных примерный
        socket.Receive(data);
    }
```

Но лучше так:

```
void Reciever()
        {
            IPEndPoint ipPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 1010);
            Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            socket.Connect(ipPoint);
            byte[] recieved_data = new byte[256]; // Размер данных примерный
            socket.Receive(recieved_data, /*здесь длина данных, если нужно*/, /*здесь доп. опции*/);
        }
```

На [этом](https://metanit.com/sharp/net/) ресурсе есть достаточно информации для начального ознакомления с темой сетевого программирования TCP/IP на C#.